# Issue showing Autocomplete results Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jsonp

I m having this script which returns me the results for a query in the following format. 
For example for an query "fb" the results are as follows

```
 ["fb",["fb","fbi","fbi most wanted","fbi jobs","fb banners","fbook","fb covers","fbanners","fbisd","fbop",],[],[]]
```

I m using the following Jquery code

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "s.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "q" : request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response(data[1]);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

It doesnt show me the results. 
Can you please correct me, where am I going wrong !

Comment: First of all, the JSON is wrong (extra comma). jQuery autocomplete widget will fail. Also, can you explain what the two empty [] are for?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zFdWZ/

It seems that: your response data actually equals ["fb"].

Why?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ check out the **Expected data format**:

> The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two
>   variants:
>
> ```
> An Array of Strings:
> [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
> [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
> ```

Comment: Do you think it has to do with the comma that appears at the end of the last element in the array ["fb",["fb","fbi","fbi most wanted","fbi jobs","fb banners","fbook","fb covers","fbanners","fbisd","fbop",],[],[]];

Comment: you can try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/yXFBL/ && http://jsfiddle.net/8LzTk/

Comment: as u can see, i has nothing to do with the comma, on the contrary, autocomplete ignores the last comma~

Comment: jQuery-ui autocomplete uses $.parseJSON to parse data sent by server and _it will fail_ if the extra comma is present.